# Is ionic fast enough for a painting and drawing application?

Tags: ionic-framework, webgl, paint

I want to make a painting and drawing application for both desktop and mobile. Is Ionic fast enough? And does it support webgl?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic will the native web-view/browser (if you build with cordova) on the device so if you can find a website on your device that can do what your wanting to do then ionic can do the same. For instance I have a p5.js + ionic project that works fine.